# If we use notify_one() to wake a thread, do we still need yield() - in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, notifications, yield

***yield***(): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield
***notify_one***(): http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/notify_one/

Case:

Thread A is supposed to finish whatever it is doing and then wake thread B to do its job.

I wrote a notify_one() call in the thread A' run() function.

Is a case possible that thread A signals notify_one() but still thread A is scheduled again even though thread B is ready?

Are notify_one() and yield() equivalent of each other?

Comment: Obviously, thread A yielding will not wake thread B if it is waiting on the condvar, and the condvar is not signalled.

Comment: There is nothing in common between `yield` and `notify_one`.  Also, what do you mean by "again"? A keeps running.

Comment: On Linux `yield` can be extremely bad for your program performance. It is implemented assuming that your thread *has nothing else to do* so it is placed *at the very end of the scheduling priority*. Every other thread in the system will get a chance to run before your yielded thread does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`yield` and `notify_one` are unrelated.

`yield` is a process request (to the OS) to give up its current time slice. The thread will still be scheduled next time around. Imagine that a process is allocated 10ms. If it calls `yield` after 5ms, the OS can run another process. It still gets the full 10ms next time it's its turn to run. The OS does not have to fulfill the request.

`condition_variable::notify_one` is used in conjunction with `condition_variable::wait`. If there are any threads waiting, notify_one is guaranteed to wake one of them. If there are no threads waiting, notify_one will do nothing.

Note that a condition variable, when calling wait, must be used with 1 mutex that protects some shared state (the *condition*), and it is waiting for another thread to signal when the condition is true.

> Is a case possible that thread A signals notify_one() but still thread A is scheduled again even though thread B is ready?

Yes. With Mesa semantics, signaling a waiting thread merely unblocks the other thread. The current thread may continue running until it runs out of time. With Hoare semantics, the signaling thread will immediately switch to the waiting thread. However, pretty much all implementations of conditions use Mesa semantics.

> Are notify_one() and yield() equivalent of each other?

"Equivalent" would mean that they do the same thing. That is not the case. I think you mean to ask if they are complimentary, or if they are part of the same synchronization scheme, and the answer is no, as I explained above.

> If we use `notify_one()` to wake a thread, do we still need `yield()`

If Thread A just woke Thread C with `nofity_one` and you wish to run Thread C as soon as possible, you can call `yield` to give up the rest of Thread A's time slice. However, the OS is not required to grant your request. And there may be many threads scheduled before Thread C that you have no control over.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between both. There is a possibility that in your case you can use either of them with same effect. `yield` is more generic and `notify_one` provides more control on the flow of program.

`yield`: Relinquish processor so that OS can possibly schedule **any other** thread.
`notify_one`: Signal a condition so that **one of the thread waiting on this condition** can resume.

> Thread A is supposed to finish whatever it is doing and then wake
>   thread B to do its job.

`notify_one` is the right choice here where one thread waits on the condition while the other thread can signal it.

Comment: In what sense is yield "more generic"? Also,  "any other" is wrong, "any (including current)" would be a little better.

Comment: @Cubbi Aren't "possibly schedule any other thread" and "schedule any(including current) thread" equivalent? Except the former adds stress that a switching happens most possibly. (Pushing current thread back in the queue) `notify_one` is implementation of a specific sync mechanism while yield is more generic yielding of CPU. Possibly my English is not good enough to find a more suitable word here.